# ToString throws NullReferenceException for unit value ()

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

Say we got a very simple function

```
let fn a = a.ToString()
```

It's type gets inferred as `a -> string`
However, passing a unit value to the function results in a NullReferenceException.

In case of simple functions like above, this might be worked around easily, but I'm actually in a more complex scenario:

```
let eitherToHttp e = 
    match e with
    | Either.Ok v ->        OK (v.ToString()) 
    | Either.Bad reason ->  reasonToErrorCode reason
```

The type of this is `Either<'a, RejectReason> -> WebPart` (what `WebPart` and `Either` actually are is irrelevant here)

In a scenario where the type of `e` is `Either<unit, RejectReason>` the function throws exactly like in the simple scenario.

How can I overcome this in a nice way? 
Should the types be inferred as generic if in fact this does not work for ALL types?

Comment: Unit is represented by the `null` constant at runtime, so naturally, you can't call methods on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let fn a = match box a with
           | null -> ""
           | _ -> a.ToString()
```

This compiles down to just a null check on `a` before attempting to call `ToString`.

Comment: Please read my comment to Mark's answer to know why this one was accepted.

Comment: To be fair you could inline his solution and it might work better. You could try it out

Comment: I did try it just a moment ago. It seems, that using `inline` is kind of contagious. Using it either makes the function that calls an `inline` function to be `inline` as well, or causes it not to be generic. Look in my question to the `eitherToHttp` function which I'd like to be as generic as possible. Inlining it appears somehow not suitable to me (but maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 6):

Use the built-in `string` function instead of calling `ToString` on the object:

```
> string 42;;
val it : string = "42"
> string ();;
val it : string = ""
```

Comment: I'm moving the accepted answer tag, since, the other answer, while less elegant produces a generic function, while `string` operator seems to be somehow limited, please see my other SO question for the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371190/type-inference-on-tostring-vs-string-operator