# Type inference on ToString() vs string operator

Tags: generics, f#, type-inference

*Note: This question is somewhat related to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347374/tostring-throws-nullreferenceexception-for-unit-value), but it actually touches the issue from different perspective*

Consider following snippet:

```
let toStr a = a.ToString()
let strOp a = string a

let intToStr = 5 |> toStr
let floatToStr = 5.0 |> toStr

let intStrOp = 5 |> strOp
let floatStrOp = 5.0 |> strOp //type inference error
```

While the `strOp` function uses what appears to be more elegant solution, and is able to convert a unit value to string as well, it seems not to be truly generic since it's type gets constrained during it's first usage (even the type inferred is `obj -> string`, not `'a -> string`)

Why doesn't string operator work in such a generic way? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `let inline strOp a = string a`

Comment: Is this the famous trick for achievieng higher kinded polymorphism here? If my question is about that, why does the ToString example work? I don't get the difference.

Comment: Because `toStr` is a true generic function, whereas `strOp` instantiates an inline function with statically resolved type constraints, but is not itself inline, so doesn't carry over the genericity. This may help in explaining the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445828/f-generics-function-overloading-syntax/30446386#30446386

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `string` uses static member constraints (see [the definition](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4485)) while `ToString` is an ordinary method available on any object and so the compiler treats the `ToString` invocation as generic code that does not constrain the instance type in any way.

Static constraints and (non-static) generics work in different ways when they are used in (otherwise unconstrained) `let`-bound function:

- For generic code, the compiler propagates the genericity and makes the `let`-bound function you wrote generic too.
- For static member constraints, the compiler specializes the code based on the first use. As mentioned in the comments, you can avoid this by using `inline`, which allows static member-based genericity to propagate in the same way as ordinal generic code.

I think the only reason why the `string` function uses statically resolved type constraints is that it allows it to specialize as ordinary `ToString` call for primitive types, but still handle `null` values in custom way for objects - `toStr null` throws an exception but `strOp null` returns an empty string!

Comment: I don't think handling nulls is the reason for `string` to have static constraints. If you look at [its definition](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4485), those type specializations look rather performance-oriented - i.e. generating​ `call` instead of `callvirt` for known primitive types.  And the null check itself is perfectly well performed in [`anyToString`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L898) via boxing, without static constraints.